# Number of cases in which $x + y + z$ is an even number?

Tags: combinatorics

- In a box there are $35$ balls numbered from $01$ to $35$.
- Three balls are removed from this box, without replacement, with the numbers $x$, $y$ and $z$.

What is the number of cases in which $x + y + z$ is an even number $?$.

**Comments:**
I tried to look for the whole non-negative solutions of these equations, but I think it is not a good way.

Comment: Do you mean "*What* is the number..."?

Comment: Does the order of the drawn balls matter ?

Comment: The sum will be even only if the 3 numbers are even (how many possibilities?) or if 2 of the numbers are odd and one is even (how many possibilities?).

Comment: Break into two cases: all even balls, and two odd one even ball

Comment: @BernardMassé $7 + 2 + 3 = 12$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two cases: all even and only one even.

1. All even. There are $17$ even balls, and the number of cases are $17 \times16\times15=4080$. Not thinking the order: $680$.
2. One even. (The extra $\times3$ is from the 3 balls and number of cases on picking one of them) $17\times18\times17\times3 = 15606.$ Not thinking about the order: $2601$.

---

Assuming that the order does matter, the number of cases are $19686$. If not, it's $3281$.

Comment: For example, if $x = 1$, $y = 2$ and $z = 3$ then we have $x+y+z = 6$ and this case is the same in that $x=2$, $y=1$ and $z = 3$. I think these repetitions have to be removed. In the case 1 we have $\frac{17 \times 16 \times 15}{3!} = 680$. I didn't quite understand how you did case 2.

Comment: He multiplied the number of choices for the even by the number of choices for the first odd by the number of choices for the second odd by the number of choices for where the even goes in the list.

Comment: Yes, $17 \times {18 \choose 2} $. Thank you for your help.